# How to get the width and height of cube?

Tags: javascript, three.js

i have a cube geometry and a mesh, and i don't know how to get the width. This is the code:

```
geometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry( 200, 200, 200 );
material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xff0000, wireframe: true } );
mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `scale` instead.

```
geometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry( 1, 1, 1 );
material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xff0000, wireframe: true } );
mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
mesh.scale.x = 200;
mesh.scale.y = 200;
mesh.scale.z = 200;
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understand your question correctly, but you just specified your cube with the dimensions 200 by 200 by 200, so you got your width and height right there.

Comment: i need to get the width and height of the cube because i must change their value, and the library dont give the methode getter.